# Need a rewrite rule based on a custom http header

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, cloudflare

Cloudflare is sending a header CF_IPCountry on all requests to our server, which contains the country code from which the request originated.

We need to redirect (permanently, including POST requests) all requests coming from New Zealand (CF_IPCountry = NZ) to a subdomain nz.foo.co.nz so that it will be served as domestic traffic and not from cloudflare's servers overseas.

What condition and rule do I need?

Comment: OK, I figured out that it wouldn't work on our test site because that is configured to bypass Cloudflare and doesn't get the header. I also confirmed the presence of the header on our production site. However, the redirect isn't happening. Is this anything to do with the way Plesk handles domain aliases?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `%{HTTP:<headername>}` var:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CF_IPCountry} ^NZ$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://nz.foo.co.nz/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: HiJohn, that isn't causing an error but it isn't having any effect either. Is there a way I can check that this header is actually being sent, like writing it to logs? (this is a test site for now).

Comment: I had to replace the underscore by a dash (-) for this to work (CF-IPCountry) - but then it worked! thanks!