# Detecting a custom header via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm offloading some pages to an external CDN (BunnyCDN), the redirect itself is working fine but getting a loop.

I was originally basing it off HTTP_HOST but BunnyCDN is just forwarding on the original HTTP_HOST, but it appears to be injecting

`HTTP_CDN_REQUESTURL
HTTP_CDN_HOST`

Is there a way I can have htaccess check the HTTP_CDN_HOST header? I had tried a few things such as

`RewriteCond %{HTTP_CDN_HOST} ^cdn.domain.com [NC]
.. the redirect`

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need a rewrite rule based on a custom http header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23121496/need-a-rewrite-rule-based-on-a-custom-http-header)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:`RewriteCond %{HTTP:CDN-HOST} ^cdn\.b-cdn\.net$ [NC]`

I used this in my .htaccess files and it works a charm!